# Rails Tagged Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I am using Tagged Logging with Unicorn and using the following configuration in my environment file.

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
config.log_tags = [:uuid]
```

So far so good.

When it comes to tags, is there a way to  -

1. Print out specific request headers
2. Print a custom UUID, i.e something that I can generate. The default UUID that rails spits out is too long.

Answer (score 2):

See some examples from this Gist here https://gist.github.com/2513183

You can add a proc to the log_tags array, which has access to the request object.

You can generate a UUID in that proc, or you can pass something through the request.env from your ApplicationController in a before_filter, like so:

```
#application_controller.rb
before_filter :set_some_request_env

def set_some_request_env
  request.env['some_var'] = "Happy"
end

# application.rb
config.log_tags = [
  -> request {
    request.env['some_var']
  }
]
```

## Update

You can use the `#tagged` method to add tags to all log messages sent within a given block.

To get a parameter from your request or controller params into the tagged output, you can do the following:

```
#application_controller.rb
around_filter :add_tags_to_logs

def add_tags_to_logs
  Rails.logger.tagged(custom_uuid_for_current_user) do
    yield
  end
end
```

Comment: With Rails 4.2.6, the tags are computed before the query is processed by the controller so your value will not be set.